# Nested enumeration spacing

Tags: spacing, enumerate

I am trying to make a nested enumerate list like this one:

[image: enumerate list]

I would like to reduce the spacing between *Outer item 1* and *Inner item 1.1*, but keep all other spacings. How?

Current code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Outer item 1
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*., nolistsep]
            \item Inner item 1.1
            \item Inner item 1.2
            \item Inner item 1.3
            \item Inner item 1.4
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Outer item 2
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*., nolistsep]
            \item Outer item 2.1
            \item Outer item 2.2
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I tried with `nolistsep` at outer enumerate and with `topsep=0pt`, but I didn't manage to get what need.

Comment: When posting a MWE, please make sure it compiles. This is especially needed when you're using a package that it needs in order to compile. Since you only are trying to change the spacing in one place, my first thought is to use \vspace* with a negative distance. It's not the most elegant solution, but it's an easily customizable quick fix.

Comment: "keep all other spacings" mean  avoid only space starting both nested lists?  or what seems more  weird to me, maintain also the space between 2 and 2.1 ?

Comment: The first option. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer that works for me, using `parsep` to avoid spacing between *Outer item 1* and *Inner item 1.1* and `itemsep` to make the spacing between *Inner item 1.4* and *Outer item 2* a bit larger:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[parsep=0pt, itemsep=8pt]
    \item Outer item 1
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*., nolistsep]
            \item Inner item 1.1
            \item Inner item 1.2
            \item Inner item 1.3
            \item Inner item 1.4
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Outer item 2
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*., nolistsep]
            \item Outer item 2.1
            \item Outer item 2.2
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```